# Nhibernate fail to delete Value Object that has null property value

Tags: c#, nhibernate, null, components

I faced this sort of problem with nhibernate:

when I try to delete a component (object that as no ID) that has null as value of a property, operation fails because condition is translated as `field = NULL` instead of `Field IS NULL`

I have the `RilevanzaFinding` object mapped as component of `Finding`:

```
HasMany<RilevanzaFinding>(x => x.Rilevanze)
        .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
        .Table("RilevanzaFinding_T045")
        .KeyColumn("int_T045_IdFinding")
        .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
        .AsSet()
        .Component(fee =>
        {
            fee.References<Rating>(x => x.Rating).Column("int_T045_IdRating").Fetch.Join();
            fee.Map(x => x.DataFine)
                .Column("dte_T045_DataFine")                    
                .CustomSqlType("Date");
            fee.Map(x => x.Note)
                .Column("nvc_T045_Note")
                .Length(100000);
        });

public class Finding : BaseObject<Finding, int>
{
    private ICollection<RilevanzaFinding> _rilevanze = new List<RilevanzaFinding>();
    public virtual IEnumerable<RilevanzaFinding> Rilevanze
    {
        get
        {
            return _rilevanze.ToArray();
        }
    }
}

public class RilevanzaFinding : EquatableObject<RilevanzaFinding>
{
    public virtual Rating Rating { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DataFine{ get; set; }
    public virtual string Note { get; set; }
}
```

where EquatableObject implements this Equals:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        TObject other = obj as TObject;

        return Equals(other);

    }

    public virtual bool Equals(TObject other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        Type t = GetType();

        TypeInfo typeInfo = t.GetTypeInfo();            
        IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fields = typeInfo.DeclaredFields.Where(x => x.FieldType.Name != typeof(ICollection<>).Name); 
        foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
        {
            object value1 = field.GetValue(other);
            object value2 = field.GetValue(this);

            if (value1 == null)
            {
                if (value2 != null)
                    return false;
            }
            else if (!value1.Equals(value2))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

now when I remove a Rilevanza from a collection of a finding Rilevanze this is the SQL generated by nhibernate:

```
NHibernate: DELETE FROM RilevanzaFinding_T045 WHERE int_T045_IdFinding = 
@p0 AND dte_T045_DataFine = @p1 AND nvc_T045_Note = @p2 AND int_T045_IdRating
 = @p3;@p0 = 201 [Type: Int32 (0:0:0)], @p1 = NULL [Type: DateTime (0:0:0)], @p2 = 'GD675PFN2GTR9EUJ3JHPG7XFX' [Type: String (1073741823:0:0)], 
@p3 = 243 [Type: Int32 (0:0:0)]
```

which fails due to `"dte_T045_DataFine = NULL"` condition, since it would be `"dte_T045_DataFine IS NULL"`

How can I make it write the right condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot with a `set` and NHibernate v5.1 or former.

From [NHibernate reference documentation (v5.1 and below)](http://nhibernate.info/previous-doc/v5.0/ref/components.html#components-incollections):

> Please note that a composite element mapping doesn't support null-able
>   properties if you're using a `<set>`. NHibernate has to use each columns
>   value to identify a record when deleting objects (there is no separate
>   primary key column in the composite element table), which is not
>   possible with null values. You have to either use only not-null
>   properties in a composite-element or choose a `<list>`, `<map>`, `<bag>` or
>   `<idbag>`.

Better map an entity than a component for this case, and add a primary key to your table, in my opinion. Your SQL will perform better by the way.

---

From NHibernate v4.1, null equality semantic support was added to filtering queries with [NH-3634](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3634). But the delete case was still not supported.

From NHibernate v5.2 (which should be available in 2018, Q3), the delete case does now support it too ([#1170](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/1170)).

So another solution will be to upgrade to NHibernate v5.2.

Comment: onestly nhibernate limitation find in documentation can be solved if they translate condition from = null to IS NULL, as done in where condition. for now swtich to default date for null value, so i always have value in table

Comment: That would be a semantic change. With SQL, null is not equal to null, and conformant bases (not SQL Server on that matter) even allows unique indexes on rows having the same column values, provided one of the indexed column is null in all those rows. Thus two components having the "same" values but with some of them null are not considered as being the same. That is why NHibernate cannot identify which component should be deleted in a set when it has a null property.

Comment: key will be respected even with null: only one row with null can exists: Null-1-1 and 1-1-1 are different, two null-1-1 row are not allowed. as posted above simply trick is to convert = null to IS NULL when searching for specifi row and only one will be found every time

Comment: "two null-1-1 row are not allowed" : by you or your db, maybe as I explain in my previous comment. But it is allowed as of SQL standard.

Comment: as explained, simple manage of null check would admit nullable column as key, blocking it by design simply remove a possibility ad is limiting

Comment: Have you seen [NH-3634](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3634)? It seems some changes have been done for accepting `null` equality with component properties at least in some cases, and they are here since v4.1. Is your version older? If no, you could still report your case and see if it is accepted.

Comment: it seem the solution to this problem. but now i have implemented different logic to bypass. but i will keep in mind for next similar case. thanks for sharing news